# Stress testing of ParseServer app

Tags: ionic2, load-testing, parse-server, stress-testing

I have an app with ParseServer back-end and Ionic2 front-end. I need to simulate multiple users to stress test the back-end.

What load testing tools would you recommend to use for such setup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your process into 2 phases:

1. Server-side testing. You need to load test your backend to ensure that it is in position to simulate anticipated number of users. In fact any tool capable of sending HTTP Requests will fit, the most popular free and open source load testing solutions are [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/),  [Gatling](http://gatling.io/), and [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/). All of them come with record-and-replay functionality so you will be able to build your test by just interacting with your mobile application and using the load testing tool as a proxy. See [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article for main features highlighted and compared.
2. Client-side testing. Even if your server responds very fast, handles enormous loads, able to scale, etc. your application user experience may be not that good as client side performance also matters. You can go for [Chrome Dev Tools Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) and/or [Intel XDK](http://xdk-software.intel.com/) which is capable of profiling existing applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [ZebraTester](http://www.zebratester.com/) and record the script for this test. The trial version allows you to have up to 20 Virtual Users and these can run multiple loops depending on the length of your test. The same tool can record the script as well as run the load test from your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I use to test parse server 
in http://jmeter.apache.org/

is a free tool you can install your computer then start testing